# How can I keep left zeros when combing columns in the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to combine three columns into on column in the same dataframe df,where df has three columns F, S and P

Example df

| F | S | P |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 0 | 1 | 4 |
| 0 | 0 | 14 |
| 0 | 0 | 25 |
| 0 | 2 | 5 |

I used code:

```
df['FSP']=df['F'].map(str)+df["S"].map(str)+df["P"].map(str)
```

the output was

| F | S | P | FSP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 12 |
| 0 | 1 | 4 | 14 |
| 0 | 0 | 14 | 14 |
| 0 | 0 | 25 | 25 |
| 0 | 2 | 5 | 25 |

the output I need

| F | S | P | FSP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 012 |
| 0 | 1 | 4 | 014 |
| 0 | 0 | 14 | 0014 |
| 0 | 0 | 25 | 0025 |
| 0 | 2 | 5 | 025 |

Comment: Running your code `df['FSP']=df['F'].map(str)+df["S"].map(str)+df["P"].map(str)` I get your expected output.

Comment: Are you somewhere convert each of the values or the whole column to type `int` ?

Comment: yes I have, because power shell understood it as float64 so I convert to int64 @user19077881

Comment: This may lead to lose left zero's, I don't know how to keep it. @user19077881

Comment: It definitely loses the left zeros. Only strings will have the results you want.

Comment: You could pad the number with left zeros(eg using zfill() ) but not in the specific way you require.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
df['DSP'] = df.astype(str).sum(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   F  S   P   DSP
0  0  1   2   012
1  0  1   4   014
2  0  0  14  0014
3  0  0  25  0025
4  0  2   5   025
```